# How to bind (C-x C-x ) to save buffer and exit emacs?

Tags: key-bindings

I have to press **`C-c C-shift-c`** on the keyboard to exit emacs. It's a bit time consuming, and **`Fn + F10 + up_arrow_key`** is a bit far in order to exit from the menu bar.

When I run the code:  `(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-x") 'save-buffer-kill-terminal)`

I get the following error: `command-execute: Symbol's function definition is void: save-buffer-kill-terminal`

Can you please explain why the function is void, and what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have to use `C-c C-C`? What's wrong with `C-x C-c`, or even menu `File` > `Quit`?

Comment: I'm closing this question because questions describing a problem that went away when a typo was fixed are unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you typo'd it.  You can verify with `F1 f` that `save-buffers-kill-terminal` is the one you're after.